# How to copy directory from remote machine which requires a specific UNIX group?

Tags: linux, ssh, rsync, scp

I need to copy automatically a list of directories from a remote machine into a local machine. Up to now, I was using `rsync` or `scp` for that:

```
> rsync -a $USER@$HOST:/remote/a/b/c /a/b/c
```

Now, the problem is that sometimes you need to be inside a special setup to enable the required group in order to be able to access that directory. For example, on remote machine:

```
> ls -la /a/b | grep c
drwxr-s---   3 some_user some_group 4096 Feb  9  2021 c
```

So I need `some_group` to be "active" in order to be able to access this group. Otherwise, the above `rsync` commands returns:

```
rsync: opendir "/a/b/c" failed: Permission denied (13)
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1674) [generator=3.1.3]
```

I have a setup `wash_groups some_group` which enters into a setup where `some_group` is active. So the question is - how can I copy automatically the `/a/b/c` directory? I need to activate the required group first and then copy them. I tried to use the `-e` option of `rsync` but as I understand it runs it on local machine and not on remote.

Is there some workaround to use `scp`, `rsync`, `ssh` or any other default command to copy the directory from remote machine while having the required group as active? Maybe some "hack" using `tar`?

Comment: I have just created a user with 35 secondary groups. All are instantiated when I `ssh` to the target account. I'd like to be able to reproduce your issue here, so I can determine the best way to access the additional groups. How many groups do you have?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience as long as the user in question is a member of the group that owns the files you want access to there should be no problem **even if the account is locked or is configured for nologin**. I think the issue might be that the files you are copying do not give full RW permissions to said group.

If it’s on the table to do so you could use run something like `chmod g+=rwx file(s)`